# Can we adjust the "Related Questions" according to entered tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, related-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l)

When we write a question title, we get a set of Related Questions, but this list remains unchanged as we enter tags. It would be useful if the entering of tags refined the Related Questions further.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l

Comment: @Gnome: See? Wouldn't I have found that if this were implemented? :)

Comment: Exactly the point I made at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42878/show-related-questions-just-before-question-submission :P (with a notice of which tag specifically it was that brought up the dupe, because I did try to search first)

Comment: Oh the Internet falls into a frozen hell when the :P emoticon is used for people that agree. What shall we use to taunt now? The waffle #?