# Yet another duplicate questions discussion

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, review

There have been discussions lately about how to improve the detection and flagging of duplicate votes. 
While some may be hard to find, others are quite obvious. One example of the latter is "how to send an email in android". 
A quick search yields many, many results (I summarize some of them in a list below as an example).
These are all very similarly formatted questions that involve two key words: "send" and "email", making it very easy to parse by any robot or at the
time of posting. I do understand the difficulty of implementing a failure safe mechanism to block duplicates automatically and the annoyance of more
orange popups while writing a question that could contain these two words but at the same time be very well original.

Thus, **I am proposing here the idea of creating a candidate duplicates list that could be accessed from the "review" tab**. 
This would be transparent to the OP (no popups) but at the same time would facilitate the task of finding dupes.
This list, together with an incentive for finding the duplicates (either a badge, rep or flag weight as has been proposed in 
[another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5))
has the potential to largely improve the tagging/merging of duplicates.

(*Edit: I forgot to add this part*) **Regarding the queries**: We can propose keyword groups or phrases that are usually employed in these cases and add them to the question check at any time.
A trial period should tell us whether these keywords are useful or not (i.e, too many false positives, sensitivity too low to be useful).

What do you think? Could this work? Is it feasible? Do you have a better option?

---

Questions sample:

About sending emails in any way:

- 2/4/10 [How can I send emails from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application)
- 8/27/10 [How to send email in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585556/how-to-send-email-in-android)
- 12/27/10 [How to send email from android (using the default account)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541111/how-to-send-email-from-android-using-the-default-account)
- 1/12/11 [Send auto email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668871/send-auto-email-programmatically)
- 3/28/11 [how to send email from an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456688/how-to-send-email-from-an-android-application)
- 5/4/11 [Can an app send an email without opening the email interface in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878915/can-an-app-send-an-email-without-opening-the-email-interface-in-android)
- 5/16/11 [Send email using android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013402/send-email-using-android-app)

About sending emails without using intents:

- 9/14/10 [How to send email from android using java mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707764/how-to-send-email-from-android-using-java-mail)
- 2/10/11 [Automatically send an email from an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961706/automatically-send-an-email-from-an-app)
- 3/2/11 [How to send an email without the button "send" clicked twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164587/how-to-send-an-email-without-the-button-send-clicked-twice)
- 5/2/11 [Sending email in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855041/sending-email-in-android)

Example of a non duplicate:

- 2/22/11 [send email via Intent with specified from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075582/send-email-via-intent-with-specified-from-address)

(NOTE: This is *not* an exhaustive list of email questions in [android](/questions/tagged/android))

Comment: Required reading for any meta question involving duplicates: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Robert, this would not be useful for those questions with one or two dupes, but for those in which you can count (at the very least) ten times the same question. Sic from the linked blog post: "Let me be clear — too much question duplication is bad. Absolutely." The above one is an example. Searching for just "i++" would give you another.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the "Related questions" list? Simply that it's accessible from /review?

Comment: @Josh I don't know how the algorithm is implemented in the related questions column, but I do not think it is such a simple query for keywords nor is intended to mark the duplicates. It serves a different function, through a different mechanism.

Comment: There's some [description in a recent post by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask) of the list that pops up while the question is being typed in. I believe that the Related Questions list is essentially the same now. The intended purpose of that list is exactly (AFAIK) to stop duplicate questions from being posted in the first place. Why wouldn't it serve to track them down afterwards?