# Similar questions in sidebar do not appear in Chrome

Tags: support, asking-questions, similar-questions

[Links to similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91568/149076) appear in the side bar when composing a question body.

[image: Firefox good]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Chrome (tested with Chrome 12.0.742.100 under Linux, in my account or without logging in, on Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu). The sidebar desperately keeps containing the “How to Format” box when the cursor is in the question body box.

[image: Chrome bad]

Comment: Is it saving your draft periodically?  It's piggy-backed on the draft saving.  (No problems with same Chrome version on Win7.)

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff If I close the question window and reopen it, I get a blank question. Does that mean the draft isn't saved? Oh, and I just tested on an answer: looks like the draft isn't saved either, and I'm fairly sure this worked recently (not completely sure because Chrome also saves form contents). Is there anything I can do to give more precise information?

Comment: Every 45 seconds when you're typing/editing, between the input text area and the preview area it should say "draft saved".  Do you have any js errors?

Comment: and it is "similar questions", not "related questions" -- just so we can clarify which is which here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must issue a keydown, and content of sufficient length -- you know, like you're actually composing a post.

If you are pasting content, this will never happen (pastes aren't proper keydowns, etc)

Comment: Ah, that was it, thank you. Bug: a paste does suffice in Firefox ):