# The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, title, quality-filter

There are numerous ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles)) questions concerning this problem. I realize this is a borderline duplicate, but I'll re-iterate the futility of this particular filter and why it should be outright removed from Stack Overflow.

Do you know how effective this is in preventing users who just don't care from posting questions with bad titles? **100% ineffective**. What do these users do?

Replace it with a synonym: "issue," "trouble," "predicament," "botheration" or what have you. Or worse, they simply work around the filter by deliberately misspelling the word or inserting space or punctuation:

- [**proble** which SQL query indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082191/proble-which-sql-query-indexes) ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:proble))
- [Where can I find an optimal solution to the Knapsack **proble***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896922/where-can-i-find-an-optimal-solution-to-the-knapsack-proble)?
- [sendmail issue “mail loops back to me MX **pr0blem**” centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130867/sendmail-issue-mail-loops-back-to-me-mx-pr0blem-centos)

and the *coup de grâce*:

- [GeForce GT555M Cuda **Problam**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8197711/1)

I mean, even Jeff [saw this coming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html). This adds **zero** value to the title. In fact, it looks worse. Why, oh why are people [so reluctant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles/111000#111000) to scrap a bad feature? All this does is:

- Prevent people who have a [legitimate need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles) to use the word "problem" in the title from posting questions with an appropriate title.
- Break the search feature because of workarounds or the need to use less descriptive titles than the error itself

This is an extraordinarily useless (and *harmful*) feature. Please, for the love of Cthulhu,  remove, eliminate, abolish, eradicate, extirpate this "feature" from Stack Overflow.

---

**Bonus:**

> <sub>So I can't mention the Halting Problem in the title? – Keith Thompson Nov 1 at 19:05</sub>
>
> <sub>@KeithThompson Maybe it's a "Halting Issue". Or "Need help with Halting". Or the "Halting thing in Computability Theory". – slhck Nov 1 at 19:14</sub>

Comment: Just replace the entire screen with a silent redirect to the question with the duplicate title and be done with it if they try and finagle misspellings

Comment: Really? *Really?* Worse than rolling comment timeouts? Worse than vote-undo-locking?! (also: who *wouldn't* be reluctant to scrape a bad feature? You'd get bad-feature-flakes all over yourself)

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know why, but I find rolling comment timeouts mildly amusing. When I get the message "You can post comments every 15 seconds. You've only waited for 14 seconds. Timer reset. Bwahahhaah!" I can't help but chuckle and accept the fact that Jeff deliberately put that in there to troll us.

Comment: Still, you'll eventually get your comment posted. Vote-undo-locking can be easily worked around (with no long term ill-effects) by editing the post.

Comment: Coincidentally, *so can this!*

Comment: @Shog9 What do you mean?

Comment: Not that I entirely disagree, but 100% ineffective is [a *bit* of a stretch](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118425/). (Note that the posts/month is definitely not accurate since it doesn't account for months without any such titles, and that there certainly could be more problem variants that aren't represented)

Comment: I wonder why I read, "Are you good to count until 15? Only 14 seconds are passed from the last comment you wrote." It must be my computer that pokes fun at me.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879502/image-upload-proble-in-drupal predates the implementation of this feature by a good 12 months

Comment: @ChrisF Hmm, fixed it. I don't know exactly when this was implemented, but there are 10 posts with "proble" in the title in the past 3 months vs. 20 total.

Comment: I mean the lousy titles can be corrected via editing. With the exception of the ones that actually *need* to include "problem" in them somewhere.

Comment: _This_ explains why spelling seems to have gotten much worse recently.

Comment: As a continued hater of the springy search bar, I take issue with this post

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I partly agree with you (see my comment on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles)), although I think the filter took the cake when I saw the "problam" question.

Comment: I will repeat my comment from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815#111014): > See, my whole point is: If I have a query with 5000 really bad problem titles (and I don't doubt that they're bad), then at least you can tell that they're bad. If you restrict people from using it, there are two possibilities: 1) they use a better title, 2) they use another crappy title without the word "problem". Either way, you can never find out what really happened.

Comment: So now we have a new problm. What is the advantage? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204197/producer-consumer-problm-for-bounded-buffer-for-n-number-of-consumer-and-n-numbe

Comment: I suggest that all questions have the world Problem replaced with random synonyms. I have a printing quandary! Someone help me with this null pointer worriment. PHP has a vexation with this function.

Comment: So instead of blocking them outright, why not show them a message on how they should improve their title and unless they fix it the question won't be accepted? Period

Comment: Totally agree. By trying to prevent noise, the developers opened Pandora Box and created just more noise, of worse type (harder to find now) - newbies are like a force of nature.. if they hit an obstacle they'll just look for a way around.

Comment: It's further proof that we've lost sight of the core issue: improving question quality. Question titles are not a problem (ahem) per se, it's the question *body*. (And yes, I changed my name in protest).

Comment: [Probleм](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512730/how-to-integrate-psr-proble-steps-recorder-in-my-application)?

Comment: @thirtydot [probrem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aprobrem), [problm](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblm), [probelm](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aprobelm)
.

Comment: a [puzzling circumstance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/problem#Noun) [has been to your computer](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A-Problem-Has-Been.aspx#Pic5)

Comment: "prοblem" Note the greek omicron...

Comment: Just came across ["prob|em"](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19139686/1); brilliant!

Comment: [OpenCart product q-u-e-s-t-i-o-n module](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21319872/1)...

Comment: 'problems' still seems to be valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281774/problems-using-melt-and-mean-in-r

Comment: @Shog9 I can't believe it took me three years and suggested edit to notice I misspelled a word. Even your  initial comment went over my head.

Comment: Wait, you mean all this time you wanted this feature *abandoned*?

Comment: As to the disguised words, any non-whitelisted standalone word with a with a Levenshtein distance <=2 (include Unicode, numerals, punctuation) to 'problem', in a title, could be automatically flagged. (pr0blem,  probrem, problm, probelm, ...). I don't see what the... *obstacle*... to implementing this is.

Comment: Just put a zero-width space in "problem"

Comment: I'm happy for people who know about this filter... It really sucks if you don't know about it. And the error message gives you no clue why the title is rejected. SO used to be a place for programmers to find help. Now you have to be an expert in the inner workings of SO itself before you can find programming help. See you on Reddit.

Comment: Exactly. When my title was rejected, I could post a title with nonexistent words like "dggurngvjr". Some **geniuses** implemented this feature.

Answer (score 126):

OK, so Kevin Montrose posted a [fairly convincing argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter) that the title filter is not 100% useless as I originally claimed after all. While I'll concede to his position, I still think users with sufficient reputation (eg: >2k? >3k?) should be allowed to post and edit the question and use whatever titles they see fit.

I find it hard to understand why users who can edit questions (including >20k and diamond mods) and post pretty much whatever they want are still bound by this quality filter. A user with this much reputation should know better than to post a question with a crappy title.

Claiming all [restrictions should apply to all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111000/149052) regardless of reputation makes no sense. There *are* [restrictions that apply to new users only](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user). If users are trusted to  edit questions without peer review (> 2k), why aren't they trusted to use their judgement when it comes question titles?

Comment: um, because they'll forget to fix the problem title? We see this *all the time*, edits that change some trival part of a post (oh, you forgot a period here) while conveniently ignoring the fact that the post is utterly incoherent, full of txt-speak, has an abysmal title, etc. So blocking titles with these strong negative signal words is very much intentional.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I will update this question and answer with data and facts. And hopefully a solution that addresses all your and Kevin Montrose's concerns. Eventually.

Comment: @JeffAtwood, even at 20k I'm still not trusted to put the word `problem` in my titles?

Comment: Well I don't know about others but this feature caused me to take better care of my titles when I started beeing on SO. And I'm pretty sure that it will cause me to rethink my title every now and then in the future as well.

Comment: @Jeff Even if they forget to fix the title, isn't the fact that they've improved the post a good enough reason to let the edit through? The question is improved, even if it isn't perfect. I think you're potentially making a big assumption that all such edits (those that exclude fixing the title) are trivial in nature.

Comment: That's annoying. So I want to fix some newbie's broken punctuation, but I don't have time to stop and formulate an entirely new title for the post right now. Sorry. Didn't realise I worked for you.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ [another post to make your case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228402/being-able-to-solve-google-code-jam-problem-sets) I tried to add the `google-code-jam` tag but it won't let me save the edit because of => "_problem_ set" in the title!? Thats perfectly legitimate, I know that and I have nearly 5k rep with the Copy Editor badge? Why shouldn't I be able to override this?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Would you please consider implementing *something* to handle the current hard filter's false positives: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275204/banning-problem-in-questions-creates-false-positives-on-named-concepts

Comment: @gideon You can click the edit tags button to edit only tags.

Answer (score 20):

Another specific use case that this makes awkward is that the Microsoft code analysis tool FxCop contains a type named `Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Problem`.  Analysis rules instantiate one and populate it with source location, suggested resolution and so forth upon finding a potential "problem" in the code being analyzed, then toss it into the `Problems` collection.  I've seen at least [one FxCop question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922815/how-to-create-fxcop-problemitem-object-with-correct-line-number-in-source) where this caused awkwardness for the asker.

Comment: So whitelist it, as @rjzii suggests.

Answer (score 19):

First thing that pops in to my mind, is the following: "How hard would it be to white-list this?"

Off the top of my head I can't think of very many situations where the word "problem" is a part of a formal title (Halting Problem, K-server problem) and as it stands right now it doesn't seem like it would be that hard to do a short white-list of phrases that are allowed through (might raise and issue of maintainability, but that can be a problem for the future if it ever comes up). Allowing a finite number of valid situations through and giving the rest a grammatical suggestions popup might resolve the situation.

Comment: TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem), Birthday Problem... any more? `Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Problem` from @JeffreyHantin below.

Answer (score 16):

Рroblem? No problem!

**Class 1**: Accents

- `èéêëòóôõöēĕėęěōŏőŕŗř`

  #### Pŕóblém

**Class 2**: Letters that look alike

- `Ε` U+0395 Greek Capital Letter Epsilon
- `Ο` U+039F Greek Capital Letter Omicron
- `Ρ` U+03A1 Greek Capital Letter Rho
- `ο` U+03BF Greek Small Letter Omicron
- `Е` U+0415 Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie
- `О` U+041E Cyrillic Capital Letter O
- `Р` U+0420 Cyrillic Capital Letter Er
- `е` U+0435 Cyrillic Small Letter Ie
- `о` U+043E Cyrillic Small Letter O
- `р` U+0440 Cyrillic Small Letter Er
- `ᴏ` U+1D0F Latin Letter Small Capital O

## ᴾᴿᴼᴮᴸᴱᴹ

## ᴘʀᴏʙʟᴇᴍ

## ֍֎֍֎֍֎

## PR֍BLEM PR֎BLEM

Comment: and at this point, the user has taken actual effort to work things around. Hopefully not more actual effort than was spent writing the question. Mission Accomplished?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did went through "Character Map" in Windows. Did you notice my username?

Comment: *Actual effort* ;p And yes, I did

Comment: But the main problem I see with this is that it breaks search. For example if someone googles an error message that contains a word that has "problem" in it.