# Houston, we have a porblem

Tags: discussion, title, filtering, quality-filter, question-restrictions

Since [it's forbidden to use the word "problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles) in titles, and there's not even a way [for experienced users to add it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles) (or [mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/moderators-should-be-immune-to-the-word-filters-in-titles)) we all know users just get around that filter by typing various permutations of the word "problem".

The filter has [scientifically™ been proven effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter?lq=1). The bottom line there was:

> "Hacking around" the filter is in fact very very rare.

I beg to disagree. I tried searching Stack Overflow for the following variations of the title:

```
problme probelm probeml probmle probmel prolbem prolbme prolebm prolemb prolmbe prolmeb proeblm proebml proelbm proelmb proembl proemlb
```

These are just a couple of permutations from 5040 possible ones. I also tried searching for variations with left out letters, like `proble`, or `prblm`. Here's just a graph of a subset from maybe 20 searches—but in reality, there might be more ways to get around the filter:

[image]

Was this ever intended? I know it saves a lot of bad titles from being created, but on the other hand it enforces *even worse* titles as well. 3% based on the [above stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter?lq=1) aren't much, but they're 3% crap the filter actively provokes.

Now, my questions up for discussion are:

- **What are we going to do** about this large number of porblematic posts?
  It seems *almost* impossible to fix all those. We now have a really good review system that allows people to dig through low quality posts the entire day, so that'd be a way to address this of course.
- Are there any plans of **getting rid of the filter again?**
  This, at least, would give you a good indicator of poor quality. If a post title contains the word "problem" you instantly know something's off. Why not have it reviewed? I understand that some people will choose a better title after being blocked, but I don't even want to start looking at the number of those who merely did a `s/problem/issue`, or even worse, just used "problems" (because that's not blocked, just sayin').

In the end I'm just thinking if there was a way to clean up the back log on this, or how to prevent more posts of this sort in the future, even with a title filter in place if it has to be.

Comment: I agree, [something should be done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem).

Comment: I think a "Filtered Questions" review queue would be useful for questions which pop up using a word that is commonly associated with poor titles, or even for titles which appear to include a tag in them.

Comment: Excluding "problem" (which only shows up in the title of posts from before the filter was added, and so shouldn't be considered) and ignore occurrences in the body of the post (because we're discussing the title) and you have less than 100 matches. Your point is misleading.

Comment: You mean, "Houston, we have an [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aissue)". ;)

Comment: So, what I'm hearing is that we need to blacklist another 5039 words... :)

Comment: Nice, even though you missed [my favorite workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=probIem).

Comment: @PopularDemand It's a good thing Firefox uses a different font when showing the target of the link you hover over otherwise I would have taken a while to spot the difference. Nice workaround. Of course the moment someone changes fonts it comes unstuck and there will be another meta post saying we have to fix the mis-spellings.

Comment: Do all of the aforementioned permutations start with the letter "P"?

Comment: @robert No, but I have no idea how creative users are in attempting to circumvent filters. There might be less permutations that make sense. I also didn't include those with removed characters or "prblm"

Comment: So what you're saying is you purposely ignored melborp? How could you do such a thing!?

Comment: @PopularDemand Fixed these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320423/what-is-wrong-with-my-logic-for-the-divide-and-conquer-algorithm-for-closest-pai and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066234/the-skyline-problem

Comment: "What are we going to do about this large number of porblematic posts?" To fix or not to fix, that is the question. Whether 'tis nobler in the mind?

Comment: Did you even look through your search results?  On page 2 it runs out of results in the title and just shows another dozen pages of people misspelling "problem" in the body.  These are mostly typos you've found, not title filter work-arounds.

Comment: I agree with @BilltheLizard, what we have are roughly ~60 questions where the word was misspelled, some of which might have been in an effort to evade the word filter. I think this narrows down more as a few seem to have the _same_ misspelling as the title in the body. Gotta lvoe us dyslexics, we're often consistent :) I'll look deeper when I get back.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You're right about the first search and that there were typos. I changed the search to look for titles only and compiled a graph of a small subset before the rate-limiter on the search would have me wait for too long.

Comment: I have a [doubt](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=doubt) that Houston is in [trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=trouble) and [question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question) the [concern](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concern) you have.

Comment: Great, now every time I see the word "problem" my brain automatically reads it out loud as "porblem".

Comment: What's the problem? Same thing with question right? I don't really see this being detrimental to the stack. There is no way to stop people from misspelling their question titles, and we just have to count on the community to pick up the slack for poor quality posts by either editing or flagging.

Comment: @TravisJ Same thing with "question", of course. The whole point of this is to raise the question of whether the community actually picks up the slack. It doesn't seem to work that well. There are probably hundreds of posts that have a definitive indicator of poor quality (meaning, a filter workaround) and they're *not* fixed.

Comment: I just tried to fix a typo in a question about the Traveling Salesman Prblem. Didn't work.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that human brain reads the word `porblem` that same way as `problem`. http://goo.gl/dj8EZe

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail You could use: "Traveling Salesman Solution" `:)`

Comment: @Pops I have, for now, emptied the search results for your favorite workaround by applying a spelling-friendly (and search-friendly) alternative when applicable. Let's strive for good spelling on the StackExchange network.