# SE wide FAQ correction - Section title doesn't match in section and the floating index

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, faq-update-request

In the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), the floating sidebar link named "[What if I see problems?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging)" corresponds to the section titled "What if I see bad things happening?". This is the only mismatch, as all the other sections have the same title both in the full text and sidebar. Is this by design, or should it be fixed?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this seems to be affecting all Stack Exchange site. It would be nice if it could be changed across them if it is indeed a mistake. I've updated the title to reflect that as well.

Comment: Clear violation http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110789/167443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually what happens for different sections too. It seems that only in few cases, the block on the right shows a title that exactly match the title used in the page.

[image: screenshot]

I don't think that is really a problem, as when you click on the section title on the page, an entry on that block is highlighted, although it is not so evident.

[image: screenshot]

Vice versa, when you click on an entry on that block, the equivalent section in the page is temporary highlighted, and shown on the top of the page.

[image: screenshot]

If you are suggesting that users could understand "What if I see problems?" as referring to software problems, once they click on the link they will notice the topic is not bugs, or issues with the software being used to run a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That's true. However, in the other cases the full section title is simply an expansion on the sidebar one. With the problems vs. bad things one, the two titles can be interpreted completely differently. For example, one could interpret problems as bugs, design issues etc. while the section is actually talking about flagging.

Comment: The problem is not using _problems_ in the page, and _bad things_ in the block; eventually the problem would be using a too generic term. To me, a user being rude with another one is a problem, and being rude is a bad thing. Nothing in the page implies it is a problem with the software.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm just saying that a reader *could* interpret it in a manner not intended.

Comment: I understood what you mean, but you are saying the problem is using _problems_ in a part of the page, and _bad things_ in another. That doesn't seem a problem; the problem is eventually using terms that are probably too generic. Even if I understand _problems_ as software problems, I would see what the topic exactly is, when I click on the link, and I would notice those problems are not bugs.

Comment: Well that makes sense. While it would be nice if it could be changed, I can agree its not necessary. Thanks for your time.