# Forbidding some words can make impossible to set a correct question

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter, question-restrictions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t we use the word “problem” in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles)

Editing the question ["_Problem Loading Widget" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952541/problem-loading-widget-message/6150129#6150129) I have met a problem. I couldn't save the edition after adding two tags. The reason is that the title of the question contains the word "Problem". And it **should** contain it, because the theme of the question is the Android message “Problem Loading Widget”. Trying to save the question I got the SO message:

```
please do not use these words in titles: 'Problem'. See Writing Good Titles
```

Changing the original word for something else strongly worsen the chance of correct finding it by search engines. I think, that the correct citation of an error message should belong to the rules of "Writing Good Titles"

I think that at least, the prohibition should exclude the cases when the prohibited words are put in the quotes, as a citation.

Just now I beg for somebody in power to edit _Problem" that I temporarily put there into "Problem", that **must** be there.

**Edit**

It is not a duplicate of the propositions, mentioned in comments, because
I think, that the problem is not only in the "problem" :-) Any word could be contained in some specific message in some IDE or framefork or language and so on. And the appropriate message should be cited correctly. And the decision, proposed by me is different than removing filter for some words.

Comment: related: [Remove blacklist filter for `problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789) (which is [meta-tag:status-declined], btw)

Comment: I think, that the problem is not only in the "problem" :-) Any word could be contained in some specific message in some IDE or framefork or language and so on. And the appropriate message should be cited correctly. And the decision, proposed by me is different than removing filter for some words.

Comment: Asking for the filter to be removed for words in `"quotes"` is pretty much the same as asking for the filter to be removed entirely (can you see why?)

Comment: @AakashM By that logic, we might as well remove the filter entirely, since it's already removed for words prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Amen to removing the filter entirely.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName +1. And using underscore worsen the visibility in search engines, unlike quotes!

Comment: @EsotericScreenName not disagreeing with that assertion! just pointing out that that's effectively what's being proposed here.

Comment: Dear elders! If you have closed the question about the problem, you hadn't closed the problem itself. Please, correct the title of the question.

Comment: in this case the error is just as terrible as all the bad question titles we're trying to prevent. Kind of a special case, really.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Please, whose error do you mean? What was my error? And how can I correct the title of the mentioned question?