# Should questions with code-related tags be forced to include code?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality, quality-filter

To help reduce the number of questions that consist of "write this program for me" or asking for help without any code samples, should Stack Overflow force any question that has a tag that's code related to include code before submitting? Non-code related tags such as [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) or [uml](/questions/tagged/uml) would not require code.

Do you think this will help improve the quality of questions here? Will it make the interface less usable?

Comment: What's a code-related tag?

Comment: **Forcing** users to do stuff is a horrible thing. Prompting them with "Hey, you haven't added any code, what's the deal?" would be better approach IMHO, but I regardless, I'm not sure the issue is large enough to need such radical changes. Users are [now forced to not-use "Problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem), and I stick by my thoughts at the time that it's the single worst change Stack Exchange has ever made.

Comment: Any tag involving a name of a programming language such C or C++ should require code. For tags that are not programming languages such as uml or oop, they won't require code.

Comment: To be honest Matt I think your idea is better. Have a prompt ask are you sure if you don't post code.

Comment: You'll likely just start seeing people not tagging their questions properly if you do this.  They'll tack on the OOP tag just so they don't need to add code, or remove the code related tags, etc.  Or you'll just start seeing plain text formatted as code to get the error to go away (it's annoying to see this done as often as it is already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some questions that I've written with no code:

- [Prevent tablet from sleeping while app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202146/prevent-surface-tablet-from-sleeping-while-app-is-running)
- [Perform action after form is shown.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317257/perform-action-after-form-is-shown)
- [Filter File extension With FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976813/filter-file-extension-with-fileupload)

Do you think that those questions need more code? and if so, what would be the nature of said code?

Comment: Your second question does actually have code...not that your point isn't valid.

Comment: @Servy fixed...

Comment: Your new question had code, it just wasn't formatted as code.  I fixed that for you =p

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604013/opencl-static-c-documentation

Comment: Why do you have the same question listed twice (first and third bullet points)?

Comment: @RobH was an accident

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's two questions.

Answer (score 8):

"Force"? Absolutely not. There are plenty of good code-related questions that don't show code. Granted - by 'plenty', I don't necessarily mean a majority; but it is quite possible to ask good code questions in some cases without code.

As for a 'reminder', I'm not so sure about that. I wouldn't object horribly to the idea, but I'm just not sure it would have enough effect to make it worthwhile doing. I think that many people would just ignore it, and it would just be an annoyance to those whose question does not really need code. It could also prompt some people to post huge blocks of unnecessary code.

I think - as imperfect as it is - the best solution for this is for people reading a question to leave a comment when it seems code is required but was not posted.