# Deliberate misspellings in titles to get around 'probelms' with banned words?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, title

It's very irritating to go around dealing with titles that are misspelled only to find that the misspelling is there because of the banned words stuff.  Can't we get some AI into the title parsing?

Case in point:

- [Probelm in opening docs file when created in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739842/probelm-in-opening-docx-file-when-created-in-c).

Yes, I rewrote the title to avoid the misspelling, but it is a nuisance.  Granted, you probably can't get around every misspelling, but simple 'two letters in wrong order' misspellings should be spottable.

Comment: What would you want the AI to do here? Fix the spelling mistake? The whole point is that the word "problem" is banned in titles. The simpler solution would be to [reverse that ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/) because [it's more of a pain than it is useful in improving the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/). Also see: [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107989) and [The Efficacy Of Stack Overflow's Question Title Filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113151).

Comment: The AI would reject the attempt to include 'probelm' in the title by identifying it as a (misspelled) synonym of 'problem', and would not allow the question to be submitted.

Comment: @Doorknob: And probably a number of others.  Eventually, the SO Team will realize that the same problem is being reported over, and over, and over again and it is a real problem that annoys the people they need — the people who keep the site looking clean and tidy and useful.

Comment: (also, this is annoying because sometimes people want to talk about the Halting Problem. The... um... [Halting Issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem#comment286823_110789)?)