# Make tags the first thing you do rather than the last thing

Tags: discussion, tags, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding tags before title of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/adding-tags-before-title-of-the-question)

Because I cannot get my "punch u thru the innertubesatron" working properly, I cannot find relief from the frustration that ***TAGS IN TITLES*** causes me.  While complaining bitterly about it, I felt a small movement in my brain.  I'm not sure what kind of movement it is, or what puns other than the obvious one to make about it... I did make a mockup of it like to see it here it goes:

[image: Moveng tags up top]

A large majority of users seem to believe that tags are really important; so important they like to decorate the titles of their questions with tags (I'm not talking about the organic ones; I'm not that anal).  So, why not light rather than fight?

We move the tag editor right smack up top.  Blam.  It has a few benefits that I can think of:

- Editing now travels from the general to the specific in a natural flow

  - Most general task is first: the subjects the question covers
  - Middle general is second: the question, without detail
  - Most specific task is third: the details about the question
- Tags are given a much more prominent position rather than be left as an afterthought
- You'd have to be a moron to add a tag and then immediately begin your title with it

Some of the downsides of this:

- Idiots who can't get past the fact that the title isn't first anymore
- Idiots who still put tags at the start or end of their title, with or without delimiters
- Idiots who start Meta discussions about how much this UI change sucks
- Idiots in general who peeve me right off

So, what are the chances this will happen?

Comment: Can I have a beta of your punch u thru the innertubesatron? I can live with some quirks as long as it doesn't punch *me*

Comment: Ohhh lordy, I can see it in front of my eyes: Questions tagged `why` `does` `my` `code` `not` `work` - if evil Jeff wouldn't be preventing that, the spoilsport

Comment: @Pekka: Luckily you can't add new tags unless you prove yourself not a moron.

Comment: @Pekka: [Prototype 5 is working, but I can't seem to stop tinkering with it long enough to leave the house.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LlPjT.png)

Comment: luv it! Although its original intention was something different from *punching*, no?