# When Asking a Question, show Information that tags in Title are not welcome

Tags: feature-request, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them)

A while ago, an experienced member in StackOverflow advised me once that putting tags in title like

> c# - My Title Question

is bad style and should be avoided. When looking over StackOverflow I see many questions that still use this kind of tagging in the title.
Wouldn't be helpful to show a Infobox or something similar near the title when pressing "Ask Question"  that instruct the user to not put tags in the title?

Comment: Yes, and thanks.  Also, can you please [read this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/adding-tags-before-title-of-the-question).  Do you think it would have prevented you from adding tags to your title when the first thing you do in your question is set the tags?

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ, tags before title is also a fantastic proposal +1. (p.s. I love you too :-p)

Comment: Not a duplicate in my opinion, as I'm suggesting to add an Info Message instead of removing possible tags by some algorithm. It's easier to implement and does not restrict things.