# Encourage more meaningful titles by putting the title text box below the body of the question

Tags: feature-request, title

I think, titles will be more meaningful if order of the body and title changed. 
If users type the issue then type the title, the title will represent the body better.
Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, we would have to do something about the automatic search as well. Currently, that kicks in after you've written the title. If that was delayed until after you had just spent 10 minutes typing in the body of your question, I think that would be annoying, and people might be more likely to post the question anyway even if a duplicate was found.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/adding-tags-before-title-of-the-question/106683#106683)

Answer (score 6):

I see what you're getting at and think it makes sense, but ultimately, the responsibility for creating a good title is the asker's, and unfortunately it's just as easy to shirk that responsibility if the title is below the question.

Fortunately we have lots of good editors who take time and effort to improve titles.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea.
However - if a user does not notice that the title is unrelated to the question in the first place - the order in which they type the two won't have much of a difference.

Comment: Correct.  but the idea could still improve the quality of the title. just an idea.

Comment: I'm all for improving the quality of questions (and answers)!  But like I said, its a [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) issue ;)

Comment: Fair enough:) we cannot do anything for PEBKAC, obviously..

Answer (score 3):

Personally for me, Writing a good title first helps me articulate a good description for the question. I would not want that order to change