# Can we automatically detect discouraged patterns in question titles?

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

Given

[Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

I was wondering whether it would be viable to detect patterns like

```
Foo: Does the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog?
```

in a question's title and show a sort of warning

> It looks like you are including a tag in your title. The format
>
> *[TAG]: Question*
>
> and similar are strongly discouraged and you should include tags in the appropriate section below.

I believe this could educate new users, especially those coming from a forum background.

Seriously my eyes hurt every time I see

```
iOS - How to blablabla
NSString: cannot blablabla
...
```

I'm aware of [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them) but it's two years old and it has been dismissed with - in my opinion - questionable reasons. Specifically Jeff stated

> [It's] not really a problem so long as they are not happening "too often". It is the ritual and systemic use of tags in this manner that I object to, not the mere presence of it at all.

This was two years ago. Right now I feel like this format is being abused and we are doing nothing for discouraging it.

Also I strongly believe that moving the tags box before the question title (as proposed in [Tags: Adding tags before title of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/tags-adding-tags-before-title-of-the-question)) would help a lot. Clearly people think about narrowing the topic down **before** making the question, and I think it's also why we get so many tags in the titles.

Comment: There already is some kind of detection, I'm trying to find a post where dev stated that...

Comment: Thank you, but f there is, it doesn't quite work as I see the `TAG: question` very very often

Comment: @amana, I linked the wrong question in my discussion above. The one I was referring to is precisely this one. Check my updated question and see whether your close vote still applies. Also that question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Why don't you offer a bounty on it saying that the current answers are outdated and require revision given recent changes?

Comment: I've bountied the target and linked to this question. (with the current answers outdated reason)

Comment: I haven't thought about it, good move. Thanks

Comment: And here I came to the question expecting to see someone suggesting that one should autoclose every Singleton question.  Oh well...

Comment: 5 minutes till the bounty is over...What should I do?