# Possible Tags similar to "Related Questions" under Title

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, edits, suggested-tags

In the same way possible answers (`Related Questions`) are suggested when you leave the `Title`, possible tags should be offered when you give the `Tags` textbox focus.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be done automatically to be useful, but I'd rather see the suggested questions tied to [tags as you enter them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've looked at tag auto-inference, but it results in some potentially bad recommendations.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA4Et1DiVbE

I'd personally rather have no tags than bad auto-generated tags.