# Why not put the tags entry at the top in the "Ask Question" interface?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, asking-questions, related-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l)

If **Tags** were an indented text box under the **Title** entry area, the tags could help filter the **Related Questions**.

I don't know what algorithm is being used to generate the guesses, but the tags have to be able to useful to learn on.

If there is a concern about people entering lower quality tags because they enter them before they clarify their thinking, a duplicating box can be placed where the current element is for review before posting.