# Update suggestions when asking a question using tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, similar-questions

When asking a new question, we usually gets a few suggestions while typing text in the title field. Sometimes, it makes no sense to write everything into the title.

I have this title:

> How to pass default values to templates

It will suggest me all sort of things but none of the suggestions are relevant even though there might be a duplicate hiding somewhere in SO. One possible solution would be to filter a bit more the suggestion with the tags that are attached to the new question.

I know I could rewrite my title like this:

> How to pass default values to templates in pyramid

But I feel that most titles that includes these kind of keywords are redundant with the tags that are actually used with the question and they don't really add anything to the question.

One problem though, even if SO would implement question suggestions with tag filtering. The current layout might not make it useful as people usually type tags after actually writing the body of the question.

Since tags are really relevant and it could help reducing the amount of duplicate by "helping" SO filter the possible duplicate by searching suggestion that have some similar tags.

For example if a question has a [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag, the algorithm could suggest more question that are related to [python](/questions/tagged/python). If the question has [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) it could filter further [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) could return many questions related to [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp), [scala](/questions/tagged/scala). While it wouldn't actually relate to [python](/questions/tagged/python) at all.

Since tags are required, it could be possible to put the tag bar right after the title to make it more visible at first. Update the suggestion in favor of the chosen tags.

Comment: If some part aren't exactly clear, let me know and I'll try write something more clear.

Comment: you are expected to *do your homework* before even trying to ask a question. Also you implement your tags at last while your title at the beginning.

Comment: @user689 please elaborate. I see no reason why tags should be typed last. SO is expecting you to know about what you're asking before even asking it.

Comment: Not really there are many tags that come just after you type your question, some users tag their questions as php but they still accept answers that are in jquery. Also you haven't thought about the 1 rep users: I've seen someone tagging his question JavaScript while it was totally Java!

Comment: I believe you get me wrong, tag filtering should be used to sort suggestions not in an absolute way. It should be used to help the algorithm to find more relevant questions for a title. In some case, the tags could have no or little effect. My proposition isn't about people that can't write proper question 1rep or not. It's about making question suggestion more relevant to any user that write a question properly.

Comment: In that case I'm with you man.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange is supposed to currently use tags to help filter the suggested questions as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91575/13295), but as you say in the comment, that doesn't seem to test out.  I've just put up [a feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214556/revist-putting-tags-box-under-title-box-on-asking-question-form) to get the Tags input box put underneath the Title input box, as I think that would really help the filter to do its job better.

Comment: That is still kind of strange because I did try to input some tags in a question I wanted to ask. It didn't really seemed to work so that's why I asked here. While I can test it later and check for any request being done while typing new tags.

Comment: Tested just now and it doesn't even include tags and body as Jeff Atwood wrote in his own answer.