# Revisit Putting Tags box under Title box on Asking Question Form

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, asking-questions, related-questions

There was [a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions) over four years ago to have the Related Questions ("**Questions that may already have your answer**") key off of the tags and not just the title.  It was requested in that post that to help implement this, they should put the Tag input box directly underneath the Title input box.  That question was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with an answer stating that the tags were taken into account for the Related Questions list, but that they didn't want to change the order of the question form.  The part of the request on Tag Entry was [also duped a few years later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83360/why-not-put-the-tags-entry-at-the-top-in-the-ask-question-interface), and it also referenced the Related Questions.

We now have [a new feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213672/update-suggestions-when-asking-a-question-using-tags) to do better filtering of those suggested questions based on tags, which mentions tangentially that the tags should be input after the title.

I think it is now time to make this a current, full-blown feature request **to have the tags entered after the title and before the Related Questions**.  I've caught myself many times from making a dupe because of questions showing up there, but also missed quite a few.  I think by having the tags input before the bulk of the text be the normal flow, that it will help decrease the number of duplicates that are being created.  It will also help those on all the sites to find the answers to their questions.